# Build a bayes net by WEKA API

Tags: java, weka, bayesian-networks

I'd like to build a bayes net(or bayesian network) using an exist dataset, do anybody have a demo code to learn a bayes net by WEKA API?

Answer (score 0):

//=================== learn bayes net (structures and CPTs) =====================
        //K2 learner = new K2(); // set search algorithm 1

```
    //MultiNomialBMAEstimator estimator = new MultiNomialBMAEstimator(); //set estimator 1
    //estimator.setUseK2Prior(true);

    //BMAEstimator estimator = new BMAEstimator(); //set estimator 2

    SimpleEstimator estimator = new SimpleEstimator(); //set estimator 3
    SimulatedAnnealing learner = new SimulatedAnnealing(); // set search algorithm 2    

    Evaluation evaluation = new Evaluation(ins);

    EditableBayesNet bnBayesNet = new EditableBayesNet(ins);
    bnBayesNet.initStructure();

    learner.buildStructure(bnBayesNet, ins);
    estimator.estimateCPTs(bnBayesNet);

    //=================== visualize the bayes net ====================
    GraphVisualizer graphVisualizer = new GraphVisualizer();
    graphVisualizer.readBIF(bnBayesNet.graph());

    final JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("Weka Classifier Graph Visualizer: Bayes net");
    jFrame.setSize(500, 400);
    jFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    jFrame.getContentPane().add(graphVisualizer, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    jFrame.addWindowFocusListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            jFrame.dispose();               
        }
    });
    jFrame.setVisible(true);
    graphVisualizer.layoutGraph();
```